# What is the probability of choosing a number divisible by $2,3$ or $19$ from $1,2,...,\ 1{,}000{,}000$?

Tags: probability

> A number of $1,2,...,\ 1{,}000{,}000$ is randomly selected, each number with the same probability. Specify a suitable probability space and calculate the probability that the chosen number is divisible by $2,3$ or $19$.

The probability space $(\Omega, P) $ would be $\Omega = \{1,2...,\ 1{,}000{,}000 \}$ and $P(A)= \frac{|A|}{1{,}000{,}000}$ with $A \subset \Omega$. Now I just have to find the set $A=\{x: x \in \Omega\ \land x \ \text{divisible by} \ 2, \ 3\ \text{or} \ 19 \}$. But I do not know how to calculate the cardinality of the set. Can someone explain me that?

Comment: Use inclusion-exclusion principle and arithmetic progressions

Comment: Could you do it if $A=\{x: x \in \Omega\ \land x \ \text{divisible by $2$}\}?$ If so, and assuming you could generalize, you'd want to use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: @JohnHughes If it would be only 2, I could calculate the probability but I am not quite sure how the approach you mentioned would look like. Further help would be appreciated

Comment: @Logik Do you know the idea of inclusion-exclusion principle or do you want an explanation of the principle too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For divisibility by $2$, the sequence is $$2,4,6,8,.....\ 1000000$$
For divisibility by $3$, $$3,6,9,12,.....\ 999999$$
For divisibility by $19$, $$19,38,57,76,.....\ 999989$$
But if we add all of these, we will be counting some numbers like $6, 38,57$ more than once. So we have to use inclusion-exclusion principle.

For divisibility by $6$, the sequence is $$6, 12, 18, 24,......\ 999996$$
For divisibility by $38$, $$38,76,114,.....\ 999970$$
For divisibility by $57$, $$57,114,.....\ 999951$$

So now we can subtract these sequences from the first three.

But then we will be subtracting multiples of $114$ once more than necessary. So we need to add in the sequence of multiples of $114$, $$114,228,.....999894$$

Now you can find the cardinality of each of these and add/subtract according to the inclusion-exclusion principle.

EDIT according to comment:

The sequence of numbers divisible by $3$ is an arithmetic progression (with common difference $3$ and first term $3$). Using the formula for general term, $$a_n=a+(n-1)d$$ $$999999=3+(n-1)3$$ $$n=333333$$ So the cardinality of this set is $333333$. This method can be used for any such sequence.

An alternative method is as follows: If we divide all of the terms by a specific number, the **number of terms** remains the same. So $3,6,9,12,.....\ 999999$ has the same number of terms as $1,2,3,4......\ 333333$. It's obvious that the number of terms is $333333$. You can use this method for all such sequences.

Now to clear your second doubt, those numbers will have to be excluded which appear in more than one of the $3$ sets. For example, which numbers will be common to the first two sets? The first one has multiples of $2$, and the second one has multiples of $3$. So naturally, the common numbers are the ones that are multiples of both $2$ and $3$, i.e. they are multiples of $6$.

Similarly, the numbers common to the first and third sets are multiples of $38$, the numbers common to the second and third sets are multiples of $57$, and the numbers common to all three sets are multiples of $114$. I have already mentioned above how to calculate the cardinality of these.

---

Now, to make you understand which sets to include and exclude, I'm going to take a simpler example. **Please note that it is not the same question as above**. Consider the numbers from $1$ to $30$. If you want to find numbers that are multiples of $2$, $3$ and $5$, the three sets are as follows-
$$2,4,6,.....30$$
$$3,6,9,.....30$$
$$5,10,15,.....30$$

We see that the first set has $15$ elements, the second has $10$ and the third has $6$.

The sets of common numbers to each pair of sets are (multiples of $6$, $10$ and $15$ respectively): $$6,12,18,24,30$$ $$10,20,30$$ $$15,30$$
We see that exactly one number is common to these three sets: $$30$$

Now: if we count only the first three sets, we end up with cardinality of $$15+10+6=31$$
We see that numbers like $6, 10, 15$ etc. are being counted twice. So we subtract the cardinalities of these three.
$$31-(5+3+2)=21$$
But wait! We've counted $30$ thrice, and subtracted it thrice too. So we need to count it once more.
$$21+1=22$$
We can confirm that the final set that we need is (by counting manually) $$2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,30$$
Which has a cardinality of $22$, so our answer is correct.

---

Now we can extend this principle to the question and solve it.

Comment: I had the same approach but then some questions appeared: First, I know the cardinality of the set for numbers divisible by 2 but not 3 and 19 for example, so how would I calculate the cardinality of these sets? Second, from where do I know which numbers appear more than once such that I can exclude the duplicates and then merge all sets into a set without duplicates and take the cardinality. In theory I know what to do but in practice I have no clue how to calculate each cardinality and add/subtract them - that is my main problem

Comment: @Logik Is it clear now?

Comment: It became much clearer now, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A number $n\in{\mathbb Z}$ is *admissible* if it is a multiple of at least one of the primes  $2$, $3$, $19$.  The $(2,3,19)$ divisibility pattern of the  numbers $n\in{\mathbb Z}$ is periodic with period $2\cdot3\cdot19=114$. From $[1..114]$ the $38$ numbers $$6k+1, \ 6k+5\qquad(0\leq k\leq18)$$
are neither multiples of $2$ nor $3$. It is easy to check that among the first multiples of $19$ two numbers belong to this set, namely $19$ and $95$. We can therefore say that  $(114-38)+2=78$ numbers in $[1..114]$ are admissible.

Now $8772\cdot114=1\,000\,008$. When the problem had dealt with all admissible numbers in $[1..1\,000\,008]$ we could answer $p={78\over114}$. Since the given range ends at $1\,000\,000$ we have to be more precise: From the $8772\cdot78=684\,216$ admissible numbers in $[1..1\,000\,008]$ we have to dismiss the admissible numbers in $[1\,000\,001..1\,000\,008]$. A case analysis shows that $5$ numbers have to be dismissed. Therefore the final probability is
$$p={684\,216-5\over 1\,000\,000}=0.684\,211\ .$$

Comment: My method agrees with your answer (using multiples of 2, 3, 19).

Answer (score 1):

*Comment:*  Implementing @Righter's (+1) program,
you could let a computer do the counting. Using R,
I counted $692\,308.$  [I did it for multiples of 2, 3, and **13,** to illustrate the idea without giving the exact answer.]

```
d.2 = seq(2,10^6, by = 2)
length(d.2)
[1] 500000

d.3 = seq(3,10^6, by = 3)
length(d.3)
[1] 333333

d.13 = seq(13,10^6, by = 13)
length(d.13)
[1] 76923

c = c(d.2, d.3, d.13)  # concatenate
length(c)
[1] 910256

u = unique(c)          # eliminate duplicates
length(u)
[1] 692308             # Answer
```

Look at unique values up to 100.

```
sort(u[u <= 100])
 [1]   2   3   4   6   8   9  10  12  13  14  15  16
[13]  18  20  21  22  24  26  27  28  30  32  33  34
[25]  36  38  39  40  42  44  45  46  48  50  51  52
[37]  54  56  57  58  60  62  63  64  65  66  68  69
[49]  70  72  74  75  76  78  80  81  82  84  86  87
[61]  88  90  91  92  93  94  96  98  99 100
```

Before elimination of duplicates, a *few* of which are noted by hand, there were 'more':

```
sort(c[c <= 100])
 [1]   2   3   4   6   6   8   9  10  12  12  13  14  # 2 6's
[13]  15  16  18  18  20  21  22  24  24  26  26  27  # 2 18's
[25]  28  30  30  32  33  34  36  36  38  39  39  40  # 2 35's
[37]  42  42  44  45  46  48  48  50  51  52  52  54  # 2 42's
[49]  54  56  57  58  60  60  62  63  64  65  66  66  # 2 54's
[61]  68  69  70  72  72  74  75  76  78  78  78  80  # 3 78's
[73]  81  82  84  84  86  87  88  90  90  91  92  93
[85]  94  96  96  98  99 100
```